Pycharm debugger can't connect to Docker server
I Am trying to set up the debug environment for Pycharm and Python(Flask) in Docker (with docker-compose) and I stuck into the problem stated here.
My setup of the entry point of the app: I put it before the creation of the Flask app and set host.docker.internal because I'm trying to connect from withing the docker container to the machine where the IDE is  running.

pydevd_pycharm.settrace('host.docker.internal', port=5678, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)

app = Flask('sample', template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

In the Pycharm I set up port 5678 for Python Debug Server and localhost for the IDE host name:

Then I start the debugger in PyCharm and then run the container.
What happens is that the debugger console keeps waiting for a connection and nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Can you reproduce the problem in a non-container Python environment?  That will probably be easier to set up, debug, and unit test.

Do you expose a port to the host through docker?

@DavidMaze I tried also without docker, locally, replacing host.docker.internal with localhost  and nothing changes, the execution get stuck at line  pydevd_pycharm.settrace('host.docker.internal', port=5678, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True) before printing the message  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/  So now I'm guessing it's because I didn't set any path mappings

@anaitslimane this doesn't work because when you map the port then de debugger finds the port occupied by docker. The only way is to use host.docker.internal
